# var_dump($_POST) returning nothing after submiting form to codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, form-data

my jquery is

```
$(document).on("click", ".addthisone", function (e) {
    var file_data = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=file]').prop("files")[0];
    console.log(file_data);
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", file_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('action/addimage');?>",
        //dataType: 'script',
        //cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (d) {
            console.log(d);
        }

    })
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`console.log()` is displaying file data correctly 
but the problem is that it is not appending the file to `formData()`, nor i am able to `var_dump()` the `$_post` after submiting the form. on the controller action it show the empty array
please help me out

Comment: Your controller's action code is also needed.

Comment: i am just doing var_dump() to see if the data is submitted or not

Comment: Are you sure then ajax is requesting for correct action. Check if it returns `var_dump('foo');`

Comment: yes bcz its returning the empty array that why i am sure its the right one

Comment: i am using opera browser

Comment: is it right way to append the file to formData() object and will i be able to see the console of formData after appending it in console

Comment: You are trying to upload a file through ajax so... look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Try to `var_dump ($_FILES)` array then.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function instant of FormData ?

Comment: how would i know that the formData has accurately appended the file data in console, bcz when i log the form data in console it is showing me the form data and there are so many function so i can't see weather the file is appended to form or not

Comment: console.log($(formData).serialize());

Answer (score 0):

use **$_FILES** to get the uploaded files!!